# itext7 HTML to PDF element converter in JAVA. Multi fonts created

Tags: java, fonts, itext7, html-to-pdf

I develop the creating PDF code when I added some paragraphs by using the method `HtmlConverter.convertToElements`.
This is the example:

```
String font_folder="C:\\FormIT\\formit\\ConvertIT\\Resources\\Fonts";
ConverterProperties properties;
properties = new ConverterProperties();
FontProvider fp = new DefaultFontProvider(true, true, false);
fp.addDirectory(font_folder);
properties.setFontProvider(fp);**
```

…

```
List<IElement> main_elem = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(html_elem,properties);
hp = (Paragraph) main_elem.get(0);
document.add(hp);**
```

It works well, but the problem is the PDF created with duplicates Fonts. I mean that the font was added to PDF for each paragraph was created by `convertToElement`.
It looks as follows in Adobe Reader properties:

[image]

The question is: how can I create the paragraph such that the font remains reusable as it works with adding the sample paragraph?